# what does -1 refers to, in the argument of setConnectTimeout(-1)

Tags: http

what does the value: -1 refers to in the arguments of setConnectTimeout().
Just like value 0 means, wait indefinite, what does -1 means.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(-1)
                .setConnectTimeout(-1)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache HttpClient, `setConnectTimeout(-1)` means "using system default".

Method `setConnectTimeout()` belongs to class `RequestConfig.Builder`, and due to its [source code](http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/source/httpcomponents-client-4.5.8-src.zip) (src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.java):

```
/**
 * Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * <p>
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Default: {@code -1}
 * </p>
 */
public int getConnectTimeout() {
    return connectTimeout;
}
```

Comment: what is the default value this timeout? is this mentioned somewhere.
Thanks

Comment: @YashBansal I think that depends on Operating System settings, which can be viewed/customized by user. On my Mac, the default timeout value is 75 seconds.